# regarding avoiding using column as index by default in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, which has two columns, the following is the screenshot of printing it out directly.  However, when printing out its columns, only one column is shown. I guess the first column is used by index by default, how can I add one extra index column, and avoid using history_date column as index.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `df_id_ts.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: That's not a column, it's an index. See marked dup for more details.